# Bundling based on non-existing env var using Vite

Tags: build, environment-variables, vite

Consider the following code:

```js
if (import.meta.env["VITE_MOCK_AUTH"] === "true") {
  console.log("WARNING: Authentication will be mocked!");
} else {
  console.log("Secure authentication");
}
```

If I run `VITE_MOCK_AUTH=true npx vite build`, I get this output as expected:

```js
{
  console.log("WARNING: Authentication will be mocked!");
}
```

If I run `VITE_MOCK_AUTH=false npx vite build`, I get this output as expected:

```js
{
  console.log("Secure authentication");
}
```

If I run `npx vite build`, I get this unexpected output:

```js
if (define_import_meta_env_default["VITE_MOCK_AUTH"] === "true") {
  console.log("WARNING: Authentication will be mocked!");
} else {
  console.log("Secure authentication");
}
```

I would expect `VITE_MOCK_AUTH=false npx vite build` and `npx vite build` to result in the same output.

How can I get Vite to only the bundle the correct branch when the environment variable is not set at build time?